# Adding comments to git pull requests using scripts

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket, bitbucket-api

I have a main Jenkins job, which calls other jobs using scripts. There jobs runs tests. 
After these jobs are finished executing, I want to comment about the status of the each job on the pull request. How can I do so? (A jenkins plugin or using git commands)

Comment: Pull requests are not a feature of git, but rather a feature of the Git web-app you're using i.e gitlab, github, gogs, bitbucket etc. Which of those are you using?

Comment: I am using bitbucket

Comment: Unfortunately the Bitbucket API doesn't seem top support commenting on a pull request.

Answer (score 0):

You can post your comment using below api in your jenkinfile or pipeline.
pullRequest.comment("YOur comment")

If you want to update the build status to the Pull request then refer to 
https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statuses/